# Is it possible to have PySide's QUIloader act like PyQt's uic.loadUi?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt4, pyside

So I have an application where I'm considering moving from PyQt4 to PySide. In this application, I use `.ui` files pretty frequently, with the following usage pattern:

```
class BaseGUIWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, ui_file = None):
        '''
        :param parent: parent widget of this widget
        :param ui_file: path to UI file to load (optional)
        '''
        super(BaseGUIWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        if ui_file is not None:
            uic.loadUi(ui_file, self)
```

Let's assume I have similar classes for `QFrame`, `QMainWindow`, `QGroupBox`, etc.

This allows me to create python classes that use the data from the UI file, as well as any additional functionality I add manually in the code. Essentially, my `BaseGUIWidget` class acts as if it was extending the class generated by the UI file. A lot of the functionality in the application is pretty reliant on this behavior.

However, from what I can tell, PySide's `QUIloader` doesn't have a similar functionality. Instead of 'shimming' the UI file's contents into your class, it simply builds a widget from the UI file internally, then returns it, and you then embed it into your widget in a `layout` like you would any other widget., I.E:

```
class BaseGUIWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, ui_file = None):
        '''
        :param parent: parent widget of this widget
        :param ui_file: path to UI file to load (optional)
        '''
        super(BaseGUIWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        if ui_file is not None:
            loader = QUILoader()
            uifile = QFile(ui_file)
            uifile.open(QFile.ReadOnly)                
            self.ui_widget = loader.load(ui_file, self)
            self.layout().addWidget(self.ui_widget)
            uifile.close()
```

This is a pretty massive difference. If, for example, you wanted your UI file to contain a `QMainWindow` and your python class to still be an extension of `QMainWindow` so it acts like one to other classes, you'd wind up with a `QMainWindow` inside a `QMainWindow`, which isn't what you want. It also means you have to do `widget.ui_widget.XXX` to access the widgets produced by the UI file.

Is there any way to make PySide's **uic** implementation act like PyQt's?

Answer (score 0):

use QtPy package

```
pip3 install QtPy
```

it autodetect used binding(pyqt5 or pyside2)

```
from QtPy import uic # and all other QT modules

w = uic.loadUi("mywidget.ui")
w.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
I know it is old question, but suddenly someone will come in handy.
I found this solution on:

https://robonobodojo.wordpress.com/2017/10/03/loading-a-pyside-ui-via-a-class/

**ui_loader.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PySide.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide.QtCore import QMetaObject

class UiLoader(QUiLoader):
    def __init__(self, base_instance):
        QUiLoader.__init__(self, base_instance)
        self.base_instance = base_instance

    def createWidget(self, class_name, parent=None, name=''):
        if parent is None and self.base_instance:
            return self.base_instance
        else:
            # create a new widget for child widgets
            widget = QUiLoader.createWidget(self, class_name, parent, name)
            if self.base_instance:
                setattr(self.base_instance, name, widget)
            return widget

def load_ui(ui_file, base_instance=None):
    loader = UiLoader(base_instance)
    widget = loader.load(ui_file)
    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)
    return widget
```

**example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PySide import QtGui
from ui_loader import load_ui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        load_ui('my_interface.ui', self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually I was wondering about the same thing and just tried this:

1. Copy the uic package from a PyQt4 installation to your PySide package(its all python modules, no compiled libraries, so there should not be any incompatibilities)
2. Do a search & replace on the uic package, replacing "PyQt4" with "PySide"
3. Use it:

   ```
   from PySide import uic

   w = uic.loadUi("mywidget.ui")
   w.show()
   ```

It also worked for me with the use case you describe (uic.loadUi(ui_file, self)) :)
Of course there is no guarantee that everything will work, but I was surprised that this hack made it work.

Comment: This would be fine for home use, but super, super illegal for use in a commercial application (free or otherwise) as it basically flagrantly violates the terms of just about any license. The whole reason PySide exists was to provide a (roughly) drop in replacement for PyQt with a different licensing scheme.